# Implementation of Data Fusion through (Extended) Kalman-Filter in OpenCV/C++

Tags: c++, opencv, location, kalman-filter

I'm working on a project to track the position of a camera which is mounted on a moving device through data-fusion.
The data I get is

**1) the velocity in x-, y- and z-direction of the camera from source A**

**2) the difference between the positions in the current and the last frame (in 2D, Z is not supposed to change either way) from source B**

I already did a similiar project but without any data fusion or so and used the Kalman-Filter which is implemented in OpenCV.

Currently I keep getting confused by all the different implementation techniques I found online so far.

**How would I go about inserting/combining the data I got into the different components of the KF/EKF?**

I have this example for altering the OpenCV-KF to work as EKF. It looks a lot like what I need except for my object actually being the camera itself and also being able to move on y- and x-axis, taking turns, .... Also instead of pixel-coordinates of the object I got the above mentioned data.
https://sites.google.com/site/timecontroll/home/extended-kalman-filtering-with-opencv

Unfortunately, I'm not exactly sure how to define my transition and measurement function and the corresponding matrix.

*Let x(k) be the current state, deltaT the passed time since the last update.*

**For 1 it probably would be something like:**

*x(k) = x(k-1) + deltaT multiplied with velocity(k-1)*

**For 2:**

*x(k) = x(k-1) + differenceBetweenFrames*

**So let's assume both data-sources are weighted the same which makes me think that combined it would be something like:**

x(k) = x(k-1) + (deltaT multiplied with velocity(k-1) + differenceBetweenFrames)/2

For measurements: I get the velocity in X, Y and Z direction through source A and the difference between the current and the last frame in X and Y coordinates through source B.

Does that make sense or am I already wrong about anything there?
How would I have to adjust my transition and measurement matrix as well as update my current state accordingly?

Comment: Camera movement is a linear system, shouldn't a linear Kalman Filter be enough?

Comment: Sorry, to clarify: 
The camera is mounted on a moving device with changing acceleration which is why I feared that it wasn't as linear as I thought it might be.

Still.. whether linear or not I'm not sure how to adjust my matrices to work with multiple data :(

Comment: As long as you only consider camera position, velocity and acceleration, the system is linear even if the acceleration is changing. However, if you also consider camera orientation, angular velocity, etc, then it is non-linear.

Comment: yeah so it's non-linear I guess. the device the camera is mounted on can take turns which changes the camera orientation (and probably angular velocity as well, though I'm not working with that right now). Even so I think I understood how to change the normal KF to an EKF in general, I'm just not sure how to define my matrices (be it KF or EKF) with the data I got

Comment: OK, you seem to get it, but just to be extra clear. If your state vector ony contains position, velocity and/or acceleration, then it's most likeley linear. If your state vector also contains orientation and/or angular velocites, then it's likely non-linear. Linearity or non-linearity comes from the model you are using (i.e. state vector, transition/measurement functions) not the physical system you are trying to model.

Comment: ah...alright thanks, that should make some things easier. 
I'll probably stick to the easier linear one for now then and might extend it later on.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are on the right track, but you seem confused with the notions of transition function and measurement function.

The first thing to do is to clearly define what state vector you want to consider. In your case, the position [px, py, pz] and velocity [vx, vy, vz] are enough:

**x**<sub>k</sub> = [px<sub>k</sub>, py<sub>k</sub>, pz<sub>k</sub>, vx<sub>k</sub>, vy<sub>k</sub>, vz<sub>k</sub>]

The second thing is to choose a transition function to model the dynamics of your system. Note that this has nothing to do with sensor measurements : it is only the model of how the state of your system evolve with time. In the case of position and velocity, a very simple model is as follows (but you may choose to use a more advanced one if needed):

**p**<sub>k</sub> = [px<sub>k</sub>, py<sub>k</sub>, pz<sub>k</sub>] = 
**p**<sub>k-1</sub> + dT . **v**<sub>k-1</sub>

**v**<sub>k</sub> = **v**<sub>k-1</sub>

This may be put in matrix form as follows:

```
       [ 1  0  0  dT 0  0  ]
       [ 0  1  0  0  dT 0  ]
       [ 0  0  1  0  0  dT ]
x(k) = [ 0  0  0  1  0  0  ] . x(k-1)
       [ 0  0  0  0  1  0  ]
       [ 0  0  0  0  0  1  ]
```

Finally, you need to derive the measurement function for your sensors. This measurement function represents the way the sensor measurements can be inferred when we know the state vector.

Your source A measures the velocity of the system, hence the measurement function is as follows:

h<sub>A</sub>( **x**<sub>k</sub> ) = **v**<sub>k</sub>

Or in matrix form:

```
           [ 0 0 0 1 0 0 ]
hA{x(k)} = [ 0 0 0 0 1 0 ] . x(k)
           [ 0 0 0 0 0 1 ]
```

Your source B measures the position differences, hence the measurement function is as follows:

h<sub>B</sub>( **x**<sub>k</sub> ) = **p**<sub>k</sub> - **p**<sub>k-1</sub> = **p**<sub>k-1</sub> + dT . **v**<sub>k-1</sub> - **p**<sub>k-1</sub> = dT . **v**<sub>k-1</sub> = dT . **v**<sub>k</sub>

Or in matrix form:

```
             [ 0  0  0  dT 0  0  ]
hB{ x(k) } = [ 0  0  0  0  dT 0  ] . x(k)
             [ 0  0  0  0  0  dT ]
```

---

If you want to have a more accurate measurement function for source B, you might want to add the position at previous time step in your state vector, as follows:

**x**<sub>k</sub> = [px<sub>k</sub>, py<sub>k</sub>, pz<sub>k</sub>, px<sub>k-1</sub>, py<sub>k-1</sub>, pz<sub>k-1</sub>,vx<sub>k</sub>, vy<sub>k</sub>, vz<sub>k</sub>]

The transition function would then become:

```
       [ 1  0  0  0  0  0  dT 0  0  ]
       [ 0  1  0  0  0  0  0  dT 0  ]
       [ 0  0  1  0  0  0  0  0  dT ]
x(k) = [ 0  0  0  1  0  0  0  0  0  ] . x(k-1)
       [ 0  0  0  0  1  0  0  0  0  ]
       [ 0  0  0  0  0  1  0  0  0  ]
       [ 0  0  0  0  0  0  1  0  0  ]
       [ 0  0  0  0  0  0  0  1  0  ]
       [ 0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  1  ]
```

The measurement function for source A would become :

```
           [ 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 ]
hA{x(k)} = [ 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 ] . x(k)
           [ 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 ]
```

The measurement function for source B would become :

```
           [ 1  0  0 -1  0  0  0  0  0 ]
hB{x(k)} = [ 0  1  0  0 -1  0  0  0  0 ] . x(k)
           [ 0  0  1  0  0 -1  0  0  0 ]
```

---

That being said, measuring the velocity of the system and the difference of its positions is almost the same. As you never measure position, your state might not be observable, which will probably be a problem. Have a look at the following documents for more details:

- "State estimation with Kalman Filter" by F.Haugen ([pdf](http://home.hit.no/~hansha/documents/control/theory/kalmanfilter.pdf))
- "Controllability and Observability: Tools for
  Kalman Filter Design" by Southall, Buxton and Marchant ([pdf](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.30.2399&rep=rep1&type=pdf))

Comment: Awesome, thanks for the thorough explanation. 
I'll go through this for now and try to understand everything.
I might come back to you for further questions if necessary.
Thanks a lot.

Comment: I have another question concerning the data-fusion aspect and the 2 different measurement matrices. Could you explain how to incorporate both variations according to the example in the link I posted?

Comment: Also I'm not 100% sure about your hB matrix / function. Let's forget about the calculations etc that are done in SourceB, the result I get there is just the difference in X and Y coordinates between two frames, ergo there's no velocity to consider if only looking at this Source. 
If you already considered this I'd like to know why you decided to go for that equation there.
Thanks and sorry for the trouble.

Comment: For the hB matrix/function, I simply used the transition model to approximate p(k-1) from p(k) and v(k). As I said at the end, if you prefer to use a hB function of the form p(k)-p(k-1), you need to modify the state vector and transition/measurement functions. For your other question, each time you have a new measurement, you need to do a prediction+update using the appropriate measurement function.

Comment: ah alright, thanks. about your last sentence though:
I thought it'd be possible to use the value I receive from source A weighted with..let's say 0.7 and the value from source B weighted with 0.3 to get a new value which incorporates both measurements as new prediction.
apart from that I already know that I'd have to do the prediction & update everytime I get a new measurement.
Still thanks so much for your input, you already helped me out a lot

Comment: That is not how Kalman Filter work. What you mention is closer to the Complementary Filter, which is simpler to implement. There is a lot of info on this on the internet.

Comment: Would I really use px(k-1), py(k-1) and pz(k-1) for my state moddeling? If I understood that part right, I'd rather use the difference or "movement" between the two frames (which is what I get from source B) in that example, so that I'd have x(k) = [px, py, pz, dPx, dPy, dPz, vx, vy, vz] with dP being that difference.
In that case I'd extend the transition matrix you've given by 3 rows & columns, moving the 3 dTs each 3 columns further to the right and putting in 1s wherever there were dTs before.
Else, could you explain how to adjust the transition matrix according to your 2nd suggestion?

Comment: The thing to understand is that the model (state vector + transition and measurements functions) is up to you. Ultimately, you want to model the physical process as close as possible to get the best accuracy, but you may choose to simplify it (e.g. to make it linear). About your question, I edited my post to clarify what I had in mind, but your approach is valid too.

Comment: thanks again, especially for the additional papers. your input helped me a lot already.

Comment: I actually forgot to add that I measure the "real" position in between under certain circumstances (not in every frame but every few frames) and can therefore correct my estimates. Does that change the corresponding matrices?

Comment: It only adds another measurement matrix, associated with this new source. The transition matrix and the other two measurement matrices are unchanged.